# TreeView - Refresh the treeView and expanding the last selected - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a treeview that need to refresh due to data changes. Is it
possible to refresh and select the last node that they were viewing when the tree view was been populated once again?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For auto refresh you can create some `ViewModel` for treeView. Something like in my answer [Binding a WPF TreeView to multiple Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561390/binding-a-wpf-treeview-to-multiple-lists/33562072#33562072) . To update selected item and expand it you should define in `ViewModel` `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` properties (like `Name` property, but `bool`). And you should define `ItemContainerStyle` in your `TreeView` like this.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```