# Binding a WPF TreeView to multiple Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

I'd like to display the following structure in a WPF Treeview:

```
public class Group{
    public string Groupname;
    public IEnumerable<Group> Groups;
    public Ienumerable<User> Member;
}
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel{
    public Group RootGroup;
}
```

I think the XAML Code should look like this:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource={Binding ViewModel.RootGroup}>
             <TextBlock Text={Binding Groupname}/>
                 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource={Binding Member}>
                     <TextBlock Text={Binding Displayname}/>
                 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

What I want it to look like:

```
RootGroup-Name
    -Member1
    -Member2
    -Member3
    -Member4
    -SubGroup1
        -Member1
        -Sub-SubGroup1
            -Member1
    -SubGroup2
        -Sub-SubGroup2
            -Sub-Sub-SubGroup1
                -Member1
```

I've bound the DataContext to itself so this shouldn't be the reason why my TreeView wont show anything.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I just found the solution by myself:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MVM.RootGroup}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Displayname}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

But the Users from the first level get lost.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that behavior you should change `ViewModel` and `ItemTemplate`. Here some code that I've used in my project.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:GItemViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12" />
    </DockPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

ViewModel for this. Here `Name` is name for group and name for member depends on the object. Member is the node with `Nodes` is set to null.

```
public sealed class GItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "Name" ); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<GItemViewModel> Nodes { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Update**

To set root element `Name` you can add into the ViewModel elemet like this. And bind the root collection to the `treeView` like this.

```
GItemViewModel vm = new GItemViewModel();
GItemViewModel root = new GItemVieModel() { Name = "Root" };
vm.Nodes.Add( root );
treeView.ItemsSource = vm.Nodes;
```

Comment: Isn't the scope of "Name" inside the Property "Nodes" because the ItemsSource got set before you accessed "Name"? So how would I achive to display the Name of the RootGroup? I actually dont get your example at all, sorry. To clarify, it's possible for a group to contain members AND Groups at the same time.

Comment: `Nodes` is collection of `GItemViewModel` so every node contain `Name`. I think it's difficult to unite members and groups in one node. I've updated answer for root node behavior. Also removed private set for `Nodes`.

Comment: Edited mistake, binding should look like `treeView.ItemsSource = vm.Nodes;`

Comment: Is there no way to keep my structure and tell the program:" Hey, Display the Name of the group, display the Name of every Member in the group and keep doing that for every Group in your Grouplist" ?

Comment: I've tested with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with another `TreeView` inside it, but it's not worked. Maybe you can add `ListView` into template but I think it's will not work properly, so I can't find the way, sorry..